# Using an static class as storage

Tags: java, class, object

I have a class (Class A) that has some usages and one of them is to store a variable. Then I try to set a value to this variable from Class B and to retrieve the value from Class C.

Each class is in different packages and Class A, and B are used as libraries. The problem is that when I check the value from Class C, the value is null.

How can achieve this?

Code:

Class A:

```
private static Config cfg;

public static void saveCFG(Config CFG) {
   cfg = CFG;
}

public static Config retrieveCFG() {
   return cfg;
}
```

Class B is a GUI that when a button is pressed it calls the saveCFG method:

```
ClassA.saveCFG(config);
```

And Class C has a Thread that is checking this value constantly:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (ClassA.retrieveCFG() != null) {
               System.out.println("Saved.");
            } else {
               System.out.println("Not saved.");
            }
            try {
               wait(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: Please post your code.... In theory it can work... Do you get a result from B?

Comment: The issue is probably a timing issue, are you sure you did set before retrieving the value

Comment: Like Danielson said, we need to set some code and more specifics. Are you running two different jvm? running inside and application container? because static variables exist per classloader.

Comment: Edited with a bit of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cross-thread safety you should set your shared state `volatile`.

```
private volatile static Config cfg;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it worked perfectly! 
This is the first time that I heard this word, thank you @OldCurmudgeon !